# Restrict "Make key exportable" option on certificate import

Tags: certificate

I'm trying to make certificate, which will have non-exportable private key once it is installed. Currently I'm creating cer and pvk files using `makecert` and then merging them to pfx file using `pvk2pfx` file. When creating private key, I'm not adding `-pe` option, hence I would expect my private key be non-exportable. Yet, when I'm importing pfx file, certificate import wizard features "Mark key as exportable". This makes it possible to export private key once it is imported (which I don't want).

I believe I might misunderstand some aspects of certificate creation, so, my question is - is it actually possible to generate certificate file, which will persistently restrict private key export after importing it?

Comment: @lentinant - Why does the third-party software need access to the private key?  The private key typically is used by the server not the software that is distributed.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm trying to make client certificate-like authorization. Software will access certain API, so I need some way to see if software has rights to do so. So far client certificate solution looked best for me.

Comment: @lentinant - Trying to issue certificates for each client cannot be scaled.